# How to run an example in c++ library after CMake build

Tags: c++, cmake, execution

I am new to C++ programming. I need to study the working of the library [g20](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o). I was able to successfully build the library using

```
cmake
```

command in Ubuntu. It created same folder structure as the g2o source folder structure in the build folder and a make file in each subfolder.

But after cmake how can I execute a sample program utilising the library? Can anyone please explain the steps in simple terms.

Or how can I use the library without using cmake?

I have been searching on it for quite a long time now but could not figure out how to do it.The library has provided with some examples in the folder  g2o/examples/ . I could not execute even them. How can I execute them? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

cmake is a building tool, which is only responsible to find the correct compiler to build the library, install it, and run the testing procedure (if set up by the authors).

Run `make install` to install the library, which defaults to the prefix of `/usr/local` (which means libraries will be installed in `/usr/local/lib` and executables will be installed to `/usr/local/bin` by default). You can edit `CMakeCache.txt` to change the installation directory by changing the line `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local`. After installation, cmake has done its job.

I see some demos in `${g2o_source_root}/bin` directory. simply execute them by typing `./bin/sba_demo` or `cd bin` first then `./sba_demo`.

You can use the library in your code like other regular libraries. Write your code in a file named `yourcode.c`, and compile it with `gcc -llibraryname yourcode.c`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is really helpful. Can I run it in windows by following the same steps?

Comment: Well, it depends on your Generator (compiler). Replace `make install` with `cmake --build . --target install`, and replace the UNIX directories with the Windows standard ones (should be `X:\Program files`) in my answer above, you should be fine.